# Fill transparent holes in an image with Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an image with relatively small holes caused by deleting some letters that were written over the original image. There are other holes with meaning and I dont't want to touch them. I'd like to "detect and fill with neighbouring colours" these small artifacts. This is a sample image I have (note that white here is not really white, but transparent), and below the result I'd like to get:

[image]

[image]

Further, I attach a snapshot of the original image with the text (in case someone finds it easier to treat the image from this point, instead of the transparent holes I describe above)...

[image]

How can I get this with Python?

In similar images I treated before, I used convolutional masks. Basically I define a few kernels with simple patterns I want to remove:

```
  kernels = [
             np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]),   # vertical line
             np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]),   # horizontal line
             np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]),   # isolated hole
             np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]])    # isolated point
             ]
```

And apply convolution:

```
 def match_kernel(matrix, kernel):
     return convolve2d(matrix, kernel, mode='same') + \
         convolve2d(1 - matrix, 1 - kernel, mode='same') == 9

 for kernel in kernels:
     mask += match_kernel(img[:,:,3]/255, kernel)
```

This produces a mask with 1's where the kernels have been matched. Now, I basically roll the image to fill just these gaps with neighbours.

```
img = np.where((mask == 1)[:,:,None], np.roll(img, 1, axis = 1), img)
```

The problem is that to fix this image this way I need to define many fine-tuned kernels by hand, which is an endless process (and eventually slow). I need to somehow generalise the idea of "hole". Or perhaps more wisely, use a completely different approach I'm not aware of.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How will it look when it's done please? (Just mock it up with Photoshop or GIMP)

Comment: Fair point. I have added what you requested.

Comment: Maybe you could avoid the problem altogether by improving your method of deleting the text.

Comment: The original image is very similar (I have also attached it to the question). The text consists of grey pixels, with a nasty shadow that is just the same pattern shifted and made transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gap filling is a classic morphology problem. Try this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Test\\input.png")

# Choose the maximum hole size, in this case 5 x 5
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cv2.imshow("Gaps Filled", closing)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Edit: Use the below if you need to use the binary result as a mask

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Test\\input.png")

# Choose the maximum hole size, in this case 5 x 5
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh, bw_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(bw_img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cv2.imshow("Thresholded", bw_img)
cv2.imshow("Gaps Filled", closing)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is the definitely the way to go. I came myself to a similar solution, although using scikit-image and morphology closing. I was going to provide an answer not to leave this as unanswered, but I think yours is fine so I’ll accept it as it is useful for future readers.